# how do i save array in magento session?

Tags: magento

I would like to save an array in session variable, how do i do it with magento session?
and this array should be updatable, ie., i will add values to this array at different actions performed by user.

could someone give me a hint on this..

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to use the setData method of the customer session object:

```
Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->setData( 'yourArray', array( 1, 2, 3 ) );
```

You can retrieve it later with getData and then use setData again to update it.

You can also create your own session model, with it's own identifier:

```
class Example_MyModule_Model_Session extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->init( 'mymodule' );
    }
}
```

Then you access it the same way, except getSingleton would use 'mymodule/session', rather than 'customer/session'.