# How to use session array in magento

Tags: php, arrays, magento, session

I am new in magento.My product has model type and model version.I want to pass model type and version to cart page and  checkoutpage. i have stored the model type and version in session. when more than one products add to cart their is a problem all the products shows same model type and model version , so please help.Is session array can slove this probelm? how can i do it? This is my code

Store session

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyModelTypeData($myData);
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyModelVersionData($myDataver);
```

Retrive data from session

```
$myData = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyModelTypeData();
 $myDataver = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyModelVersionData();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like

```
<?php

$storage = array('a'=>'b');

// store data so we can fetch it in subtotal methods
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setRbanhShipping(serialize($storage));

// get data
$rbanhShipping = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRbanhShipping(); 
$rbanhShipping = unserialize($rbanhShipping);
```

---

**Good Read**

[how do i save array in magento session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377776/how-do-i-save-array-in-magento-session)

Comment: when i use serialize() the getRbanhShipping() retrive nothing, it shows error